# How to assign multiple Id's to the same button

Tags: javascript

I am looking to have a button which does two specific things depending on what the value of a variable is, however in order for my code to work I need to have multiple buttons rather than only creating and using one for the same purpose. For example:

```
function createCloseButton(){
    var close = document.createElement("input");
    close.type = "button";
    close.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
    close.setAttribute("value", "Close");
    close.setAttribute("id", "close");
    close.setAttribute("onclick"," hideFields(); createPicker();")
    if (change == "set"){
    close.setAttribute("data-dismiss", "modal");
    }
    else if (change == "search"){
        close.onclick = function(){
            hideFields();
        }
    }
    return (close);
}
```

This function when it is called creates and returns a close button. Is there a way to assign the button a different id each time it is called so that they can be differentiated? Or do I need to create 9 separate buttons?

Thanks

Comment: It is invalid HMTL to have the same id twice in a single document

Comment: You can not define mutliple ids for the same element

Comment: Use different classes to your element

Comment: Just don't give it an id?!

Comment: I need to get the element though and am using document.getElementById. So would there be a way to say assign the ID of the element to button, and then the next time the function was called the ID would be button2

Comment: Why don't you just use `addEventListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this using global counter variable

```
var idCounter=0; //declare variable here
function createCloseButton(){
  idCounter++; //every time this counter get incremented 
  ....
  close.setAttribute("id", "close"+idCounter);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for